# Python : How to use find_element_by_css_selector using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to crawling news comment. I want to crawling the text, '72' from this bluelined HTML code

[image]

So, this is my code

```
per_male = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.u_cbox_chart_progress u_cbox_chart_male > 
           span.u_cbox_chart_per')
print('per_male : ' + per_male.get_attribute('text'))
```

But I have this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.u_cbox_chart_progress u_cbox_chart_male > span.u_cbox_chart_per"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.97)
```

I also use this code

```
per_male = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.u_cbox_chart_progress u_cbox_chart_male > 
           span.u_cbox_chart_per')
print('per_male : ' + per_male.text)
```

But I have same error, how can I solve this problem?

Thx.

Comment: Please edit your question with the actual html, not an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To crawl the text **72**  you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.u_cbox_chart_progress.u_cbox_chart_male>div.u_cbox_chart_per"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='u_cbox_chart_progress u_cbox_chart_male']/div[@class='u_cbox_chart_per']"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: @HyungjoonCho Glad to be able to help you. Upvote the answer if this answer was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.